# php - Joomla 3 get menu title else get article title else get archive title

Tags: php, joomla, get, echo, title

I would like to put some php in my Joomla template to call the current menu title or article title in the custom location, I got some code :

**For the menu title:**

```
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
echo $active->title;
```

**For the parent menu title:**

```
$parentName = $menu->getItem($menu->getActive()->tree[0])->title;
echo $parentName;
```

**For the article title:**

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    echo $article->get("title");
    }
```

I want to marge all the code within `if` & `else` statement.

Example: **[it's an example only, so don't be confounded]**

```
if ( condition_one ) {
  echo 'Active Menu / Parent Title';
} else {
    if ( condition_two ) {
      echo 'Category / Archive Title';
    }
    else {
        if (condition_three) {
          echo 'Article Title';
    }
} 
else {
  echo 'Get Title from ID';
}
```

or

```
if ( condition_one ) {
  echo 'Active Menu / Parent Title';
}
else if ( condition_two ) {
       echo 'Category / Archive Title';
}
else if (condition_three) {
       echo 'Article Title';
} 
else {
  echo 'Get Title from ID';
}
```

Like this, get active menu title(default), else get category / archive title, else get article title, else get the title from the ID.

So how can I do that? Can anyone Solve this?...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but I assume you are doing this in a layout override? Also this is in 1.5 right?

Comment: @Elin - Joomla 3.x, title question ;)

Comment: Then why are there sections? And JRequest that is what I don't get.

Comment: not to mention `Jsite::getMenu()` and old database queries. The docs aren't viewed a lot these days. @Arefin - I would suggest using up to date Joomla coding standards and then re-asking the question ;)

Comment: Really some of those fields and tables literally do not exist in Joomla 3.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP has code from 1.5 that they are looking to use in 3.0 and want someone to help them update it?

Comment: I hope, I can not explain you clearly. I am really sorry for that. So that the reason I update my question. Best Regards...